# Creating a Dataframe using spark2-shell and got this error

Tags: scala, spark-shell

I am new to `Spark-shell` and I am getting this error when creating a **dataframe** from a **csv** file:

```
 scala> val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF() bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")                                                                                                               
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.                                                                                                                                       
val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF() bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")


                              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are missing `;` to separate the 2 statements.

[Programming in Scala, First Edition](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html#4.2)

> In a Scala program, a semicolon at the end of a statement is usually optional. You can type one if you want but you don't have to
>   if the statement appears by itself on a single line.
>
> **On the other hand, a semicolon is required if you write multiple statements on a single line:**
>
> ```
>   val s = "hello"; println(s)
> ```

Sample working example `Error`(exactly as in your code):

```
scala> val rnd = Math.random() val n = Math.abs(rnd)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'val' found.
val rnd = Math.random() val n = Math.abs(rnd)
                        ^
```

Sample working example `Fixed`:

```
scala> val rnd = Math.random(); val n = Math.abs(rnd)
rnd: Double = 0.5940919229549699
n: Double = 0.5940919229549699
```

> So, in your case, you have 2 options to make it work:
>
> *Option1:*
>
> ```
> val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF(); bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")
> ```
>
> *Option2:*
>
> ```
> val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF()
> bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")
> ```

```
with the following output:

scala> val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF(); bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
bankDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF()
bankDF.registerTempTable("bankfull")
```

or

```
val bankDF = bankrdd.toDF().registerTempTable("bankfull")
```